# problems with production certificate appcelerator

Tags: iphone, certificate, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have a problem to recognize the certificate of production to develop app on iphone. I only appears while the developer to compile and to upload to appstore . Someone can help me on this, please .

Thank you

Comment: Production certificates are only used to publish apps to app store. If you only want to run the app on your iPhone device, then you will need development certificate & provisioning profile. Refer Titanium Docs to read more.

Comment: Or you use the AdHoc profile and certificate to generate the IPA which can be installed only on the devices whose UDID has been registered.

Comment: Ok , but my main problem is whether I need to get some appcelerator plan to register the certificate of production ?

For that I have created , but appcelerator not recognize it.

It is understood some of what I am explaining ?

Comment: Apple's iOS distribution certifications have nothing to do with Appcelerator. The process is explained [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Distributing_iOS_apps-section-27595277_DistributingiOSapps-Createandinstallthedistributioncertificate). To build an app for production using Appcelerator Studio or CLI you do need a [paid plan](http://www.appcelerator.com/pricing/), perhaps that's the cause of confusion?

Comment: Agree. I explained again .

The problem is: I have my certificate distribution ready to compile my app to upload to AppStore , but from the IDE Appcelerator Studio , I can not see on the list of certified distribution , I can only see development certificates .

Also when you open the program ( Appceleretor Studio) indicating that a window to publish an app in appStore must have an account available with " Appcelerator Studio" appears